# x509 structures no longer acessible in openSSL 1.1.1k

Tags: openssl, x509

I'm porting some code from openssl 1.0.2n to 1.1.1k, and I'm having some access issues.

For example, I declare the type:

```
X509 *certificate;
```

And later, I do the following treatment, which gives me compilation errors like `invalid use of incomplete type 'X509 {aka struct x509_st}'` and `forward declaration of 'X509 {aka struct x509_st}'`

```
if ((certificate->cert_info) && (certificate->cert_info->signature) && (certificate->cert_info->signature->algorithm))
{
...
}
```

I understand that these structures are opaque now and I can no longer access them with pointers. How can I access them using openssl 1.1.1k? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the certificate cert_info.signature data using `X509_get0_tbs_sigalg()`:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_get0_tbs_sigalg.html

This returns an `X509_ALGOR` object which you can query to get algorithm information using `X509_ALGOR_get0`:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_ALGOR_get0.html